# Create custom filter Angular JS in component with Webpack (FountainJS)

Tags: angularjs, filter, webpack, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to create a custom filter in Angualr JS (I create my seed project with [FountainJS](http://fountainjs.io/) , I set Angular JS, Webpacks and Babel)

The problem is that the fact of write code in this component way in Angular JS with Webpacks, I don't know how to set a custom filter, I tried to create it like a simple function that return another function like the normal filters as said Todd Mott [here](https://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/).

Well, here is my component.

```
class ContactsController{
  /** @ngInject */
  constructor($http) {
    $http
      .get('app/contacts/contacts.json')
      .then(response => {
        this.contacts = response.data;
      });

  }

  getContacts(){
    return this.contacts;
  }

  setFilterContacts(filter){
    this.filterSelected = filter;
  }

  getFilterContacts(){
    return this.filterSelected;
  }

  getContactsFiltered(){
    return function(){
      this.filter = getFilterContacts();
      if (this.filter === undefined){
        return this.getContacts();
      }

      this.contactsFiltered = [];
      this.contacts.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
        if (item.name.startsWith(this.filter)){
          this.contactsFiltered.push(item);
        };
      });

      return this.contactsFiltered;
    };
  }

}

export const contacts = {
  templateUrl: 'app/contacts/contacts.html',
  controller: ContactsController
};
```

Here is the view with the directive and the filter

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: #333333;">
            <li style="float: left;"><button ng-click="$ctrl.setFilterContacts()">Todos</button></li>
            <li style="float: left;"><button ng-click="$ctrl.setFilterContacts('j')">a</button></li>
        </ul>

        <intelico-contact ng-repeat="contact in $(ctrl.contacts | orderBy: 'name' | $ctrl.getContactsFiltered()" contact="contact">
        </intelico-contact>
```

I get this error in the console

```
angular.js?3437:13708 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 42 of the expression [($ctrl.contacts | orderBy: 'name' | $ctrl.getContactsFiltered())] starting at [.getContactsFiltered())].
            http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$parse/syntax?p0=.&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B)%5D&p2=42&p3=(trl.contacts%20%7C%orderBy%3A%20'name'%20%7C%20%24ctrl.getContactsFiltered())&p4=.getContactsFiltered())
                at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:128:2), <anonymous>:68:12)
                at Object.throwError (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:128:2), <anonymous>:14343:11)
                at Object.consume (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:128:2), <anonymous>:14355:12)
                at Object.primary (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:128:2), <anonymous>:14217:12)
                at Object.unary (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:128:2), <anonymous>:14209:19)
                at Object.multiplicative (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:128:2), <anonymous>:14196:21)
                at Object.additive (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:128:2), <anonymous>:14187:21)
                at Object.relational (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:128:2), <anonymous>:14178:21)
                at Object.equality (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:128:2), <anonymous>:14169:21)
                at Object.logicalAND (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:128:2), <anonymous>:14161:21)(anonymous function) @ angular.js?3437:13708(anonymous function) @ angular.js?3437:10347invokeLinkFn @ angular.js?3437:9816nodeLinkFn @ angular.js?3437:9215compositeLinkFn @ angular.js?3437:8510nodeLinkFn @ angular.js?3437:9210(anonymous function) @ angular.js?3437:9553processQueue @ angular.js?3437:16170(anonymous function) @ angular.js?3437:16186$eval @ angular.js?3437:17444$digest @ angular.js?3437:17257$apply @ angular.js?3437:17552done @ angular.js?3437:11697completeRequest @ angular.js?3437:11903requestLoaded @ angular.js?3437:11836
```

Also tried like this but I have another error:

```
<intelico-contact ng-repeat="contact in ( $ctrl.getContactsFiltered() | orderBy: 'name')" contact="contact"></intelico-contact>





        Error: [orderBy:notarray] Expected array but received: function ()
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/orderBy/notarray?p0=function%20()
            at eval (eval at <anonymous> (index.js:128), <anonymous>:68:12)
            at eval (eval at <anonymous> (index.js:128), <anonymous>:21428:30)
            at fn (eval at compile (eval at <anonymous> (index.js:128)), <anonymous>:4:374)
            at regularInterceptedExpression (eval at <anonymous> (index.js:128), <anonymous>:15831:55)
            at Scope.$digest (eval at <anonymous> (index.js:128), <anonymous>:17277:34)
            at Scope.$apply (eval at <anonymous> (index.js:128), <anonymous>:17552:24)
            at done (eval at <anonymous> (index.js:128), <anonymous>:11697:47)
            at completeRequest (eval at <anonymous> (index.js:128), <anonymous>:11903:7)
            at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (eval at <anonymous> (index.js:128), <anonymous>:11836:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter is not something that you return from controller method. 
Filter is something that you register on module using `.filter` method. 
Examples in article that you linked clearly show that.

For example if I want to add new filter I do something like this:

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').filter('onlyEvenTimes2', () => { 
  return values => values
    .filter(value => value % 2 === 0)
    .map(value => value * 2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  {{ [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] | onlyEvenTimes2 }}
</div>
```

As you can see it required to pass name and function that return filter function to module `.filter` method. It is required to do so like this, because filter can and should be used multiple times (otherwise you can just transform your data in controller, no need for filter). Also function that return filter can make use of dependency injection.

Comment: Yes, but im coding like 'components' style in Angular and the syntax and the way of write the code in Angular change a little bit, look at this:

https://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method/

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03

Comment: You are mistaken, there is no such thing like component like filters. You should learn difference. components, filters, services and so on have different use cases. You cant and should not try to use component like golden hamer.